# Sidekiq worker is not updating latest value inside a field

Tags: ruby, heroku, sidekiq

Sidekiq worker is unable to run the job and update the field instantly. It is taking previous values instead of latest value

`update_client_branch_address` should update all the client_branch address in the background when the address is edited.

I tried running my code locally, running sidekiq services locally and it is working fine when I am trying to update the values. However, when I am deploying my code to `staging` it is not working properly and appending the previous values instead of the new one.

Context :

```
def update_order_address # inside app/model/client.rb
 return unless will_save_change_to_address?
 options = { client_id: id, previous_value: address_was }
 UpdateAddressWorker.perform_async(options = options || {})
end
```

``

```
class UpdateAddressWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(options={})
    return if options.empty?
   
   UpdateAddressService.new(options: options).execute
  end
```

end

`UpdateAddressService` --> calls the below method

`client,client_branches.each(&method(:update_client_branch_address))`

Normally,

```
Order_address = client_code + client_address ==> { 004 abc}
```

when I edit the `client_address` form and add the new value `xyz` it should update all future Order_address with new value of client_addresss i.e { 004 xyz}

However, { 004 xyz} is only updated when I once again update the client_address. so on third updation with `pqr` value

Expected value:
Order_address = client_code + client_address ==> { 004 pqr}

Outcome value:
Order_address = client_code + client_address ==> { 004 xyz}

Comment: You are passing the old address to the worker `options = { client_id: id, previous_value: address_was }`. Why do you expect the worker to update orders with the new value? Please share the code that loads the new value.